# best Way to learn javascript is through a book or Paid course (i already have some basics knowledge about Programming)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, reactjs, react-native

best Way to learn javascript is through a book or Paid course  (i already have some basics knowledge about Programming) ?

Comment: https://javascript.info/

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This site isn't for asking questions about what to read or study, so your question will be closed. You're welcome to ask technical questions. I will point out that there's a third kind of resource besides books or paid courses: online tutorials. Free Code Camp has some good ones. There are many others. Use your favorite search engine.

Comment: The short answer is:  "what works best for *you?*  You can learn from a book, or you can attend live classes where you work with a professional instructor *and* fellow students.  I "learned from a book" but taught such classes and they were always well-received.  The right answer for *you* ... is entirely up to *you.*  Both resources are available, these days, without walking into a physical classroom.  There are also "tutor" sites.  Many good options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some Udemy Courses. You can learn from them.. There is a 7/8 hours crash course of JavaScript in youtube which is made by CleverProgrammer (https://youtu.be/Qqx_wzMmFeA). And also see some basics of JS from Mosh. You can find them in youtube.  And yes,You may follow a course book.But to me, it's better to learn from websites(W3School.com) and tutotrial(Youtube)